# Howto return 502 error code instead of 404 when PHP-FPM fails

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, fastcgi

My  server configuration looks like this:
Nginx1 (proxycache) <---------> Nginx2  <-> PHP-FPM

When PHP-FPM fails because of the process is down ( errorconnect to unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed: No such file or directory while connecting to upstream) or because of pm.max_children has been reached Nginx2 returns a 404. I have looked if this behavior is set anywhere in my configuration but it looks it's the default.

If Nginx1 gets a 502 error code from Nginx2 will show the stale version of the page and that's why I want it to return a 502 code. I know I can configure Nginx to use the stale version when it gets a 404 from upstream but it there is no way to differentiate that from a normal 404 when a file gets deleted.

Comment: What is your complete nginx confuguration?

Answer (score 3):

Usually this happens if you configure php to display errors:

```
 php_admin_value[display_errors] = On
```

nginx considers the error msg a valid page and changes the http status code.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421240/why-does-display-errors-change-the-http-status-code

Comment: that looks correct, but it seems to me that it should be logged as a bug with PHP - displaying errors shouldn't interfere with the protocol, look what it does to nginx

Comment: I will review this but I'm referring to situations when php-fpm is not processing the request, not when there is an error in the PHP code (like the question you mention), so I don't think the PHP configuration matters. One of the tests I do is literally executing `service php7.0-fpm stop`. In that case Nginx2 returns a 404 ( ( errorconnect() to unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory)) and I want it to return a 502.